# Как объяснить, почему ставится тире?

Tags: пунктуация

*Паратино - невысокий, крепкий, просмоленный грек.*

Comment: Вообще-то, alt  [держим] и 0151 (alt+0151 на правой части клавиатуры). Самое странное, что мой компьютер (или какая-то из поддерживающих программ?) "не берёт".

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, попробуйте альт держать на левой части клавиатуры и включить Нумпад (клавиша NumLock).

Comment: О-и... Получилось. Кланяюсь-кланяюсь. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Тире ставится между подлежащим (*Паратино*) и сказуемым (*грек*) с нулевой связкой, если главные члены выражены существительными в именительном падеже, а также словосочетаниями, их содержащими.

**Паратино — невысокий, крепкий, просмоленный грек.**

*— Прокатилов — сила! — начала компания утешать Стручкова* (А. П. Чехов. На гвозде).

*Буратино — деревянная кукла, которую бедный шарманщик папа Карло вырезал из полена. Жизнь странного мальчика — сплошная нелепость.*

[Все случаи постановки тире](http://rus.1sep.ru/article.php?ID=200202402)

Answer (score 0):

Тире ставится на основании того, что оба существительных находятся в **именительном** падеже. Также оно несёт пояснительную интонацию, показывая то, кем является Паратино.

Comment: Было бы правильно привести ссылку на соответствующее Правило.

Comment: Было бы... Но искать правило долговато будет.

Comment: Ага, конечно... Выше написан ответ с таким же содержанием, но нет... Надо же каждый раз "реферат" расписывать... Прав был Niemand.

Comment: Зря Вы ТАК... Дело не в рефератах! Содержание Вашего ответа не есть **такое же** по смыслу. Вот предложение: _Буратино, деревянная кукла, был любознательным._ Оба существительных находятся в именительном падеже, но тире ведь нет.